# Why would a passenger airliner be missing windows in the fuselage?

Tags: windows, fuselage

On many airplanes (you can take the [A330](https://www.google.it/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii6ej4x67JAhVGcRQKHZ0DBvkQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DsTQo8k_NfaA&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d24&psig=AFQjCNEtTKDsMZ2HeVjdOcQ9A2-Hqso5ag&ust=1448643557470799) to make an example), the fuselage is not completely covered by windows. In some cases it is due to the presence of the lateral emergency exit, in some other cases I am not sure about the reason. Usually it's above the wings, so I made my idea but I want to know for sure the real reason!

In the linked video, for example, one windows is missing under the "R" of the "Garuda" logo in the fuselage.

Comment: I have seen similar missing windows in B737

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of them are where there is a divider between sections or there is a lavatory there.

Here are the layouts for the Garuda A330-200 and -300. As you can see the divider between the classes (Between Blue row 11 and green row 21) and the lavatories (Between rows 31 and 32) are located where the missing windows are in the video.

-300:

[image]

-200:

[image]

Images by Garuda Airlines

Comment: Some airline which does not have divider also have missed window; for example, [Air Asia X](https://www.planespotters.net/photo/635751/9m-xxv-airasia-x-airbus-a330-343) also missed the window between frame 39.1 and 39.2, exactly the location under Garuda Logo.

Comment: I think you might've uploaded the same image twice.

Answer (score 3):

Quite often there is an air conditioning riser duct in the fuselage wall where there is a blank window space, due to the capacity requirement for the duct itself which is unable to fit between the windows.